# In the sequence $1,4,11,26$… each term is $2⋅(n-1)^{th}$ term $+ n$. What is the $n^{th}$ term?

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus

I readily see that it is $2^{n+1} - (n+2)$ but how can I deduce the $n^{th}$ term from the given pattern i.e. $2⋅(n−1)^{th}$ term $+n$ .

Comment: Are you asking how to get from $a_n=2a_{n-1}+n$ to $a_n=2^{n+1}-n-2$?

Comment: [This might help you in future](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: These numbers occur in the first column of the Eulerian numbers https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eulerian_number

Comment: @Sil Yes exactly

Comment: @steven Gregory I am stuck. Explain in whichever simplest way possible please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like this problem.

$$\begin{align}
a_n&=2a_{n-1}+n \\
&=2(2a_{n-2}+n-1)+n \\ 
&=2^2a_{n-2}+(2^1+2^0)n-2 \\
&=2^2(2a_{n-3}+n-2)+(2^1+2^0)n-2 \\
&=2^3a_{n-3}+(2^2+2^1+2^0)n-(1\cdot2^1+2\cdot2^2) \\
&=2^4a_{n-4}+(2^3+2^2+2^1+2^0)n-(1\cdot2^1+2\cdot2^2+3\cdot2^3) \\
&\vdots \quad \quad \text{(and after i steps)} \\
&=2^ia_{n-i}+(2^{i-1}+ \cdots +2^1+2^0)n-(1\cdot2^1+2\cdot2^2+ \cdots +(i-1)\cdot2^{i-1}) \\
&=2^ia_{n-i}+\Sigma_1-\Sigma_2
\end{align}$$
It wasn't obvious at all what $\Sigma_2$ was to me, so I had to work it out that $\sum_{k=1}^{i-1} k\cdot 2^k=(i-2)2^{i}+2$

More obvious was $\sum_{k=0}^{i-1} 2^k=2^i-1$

Continuing from above
$$\begin{align}
a_n&=2^ia_{n-i}+\Sigma_1 n-\Sigma_2 \\
&=2^ia_{n-i}+(2^i-1)n-[(i-2)2^{i}+2] \\
&=2^i(a_{n-i}+n-i+2)-n-2 \\
&\text{i is a free variable, can choose i=n-1 and use that a_1=1} \\
&=2^{n-1}(1+1+2)-n-2 \\
&=2^{n+1}-n-2
\end{align}$$

-----------------------------------------------EDIT

Sure!!  I'll assume you're comfortable with the geometric series.

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{i=1}^m i\cdot 2^i&=1\cdot 2^1+2\cdot 2^2+3\cdot 2^3+4\cdot 2^4+5\cdot 2^5+6\cdot 2^6 + \cdots +m\cdot 2^m\\
&=(2^1+2^2+\cdots+2^m)+(2^2+2^3+\cdots+2^m)+(2^3+2^4+\cdots+2^m)+\cdots+(2^m) \\
&=\Sigma_1 + (\Sigma_1-2^1)+(\Sigma_1-(2^1+2^2))+\cdots +(\Sigma_1-(2^1+\cdots+2^{m-1})) \\
&=m \bigg[\Sigma_1\bigg]-\bigg[(2^1)+(2^1+2^2)+\cdots+(2^1+\cdots+2^{m-1)}\bigg]
\end{align}$$

Here's where familiarity with geometric series takes over.  Now for $\Sigma_1=\sum_{i=1}^{m}2^i=2^{m+1}-2$

The quantity in the right set of brackets is a sum of geometric sums:  $$\begin{align}
\sum_{h=1}^{m-1} \sum_{j=1}^h 2^j&=\sum_{h=1}^{m-1}(2^{h+1}-2) \\
&=\sum_{h=1}^{m-1}2^{h+1}-2(m-1) \\
&=2\sum_{h=1}^{m-1}2^h-2(m-1) \\
&=2(2^m-2)-2(m-1)
\end{align}$$

So continuing from above:

$$\begin{align} 
\sum_{i=1}^m i\cdot 2^i&=m \bigg[2^{m+1}-2\bigg]-\bigg[2(2^m-2)-2(m-1)\bigg] \\&=(m-1)2^{m+1}+2
\end{align}$$

Comment: I am a little stuck with getting the same $\Sigma_2$ as yours. Could you show how you got that? TIA

Comment: Yup....please see edit

Comment: So in the right set of brackets there are total $m-1$ brackets, right?

Comment: Yes.   Just replace the upper sum bound from $m$ to$ m-1$

Answer (score 5):

Hint: $a_n = 2 a_{n-1} + n \iff a_n + n + 2 = 2 \left(a_{n-1} + (n-1) + 2\right)\,$, so $a_n+n+2$ is a geometric progression with common ratio $2$.

---

[ *EDIT* ]   To followup on comments about doing it "*by inspection*", the heuristic would go like:

- try adding *some* multiple of $n$ on both sides of the given recurrence in such a way that the terms in $n$ can be "folded" into / incorporated into the general term of a suitable sequence

$$
\require{cancel}
\begin{align}
a_n \,+\, \color{red}{?} \cdot n &\,=\, 2 a_{n-1} \,+\, \color{red}{?} \cdot n \,+\, n \\
&\,=\, 2 \big( a_{n-1}\,+\, \color{red}{?} \cdot (n-1) \big) \,-\, \bcancel{\color{red}{?} \cdot n} \,+\, 2 \,+\, \bcancel{n}
\end{align}
$$

- it follows that $\color{red}{?} = 1$ for the free terms in $n$ to cancel out, which leaves

$$
a_n \,+\, n \,=\, 2 \big( a_{n-1}\,+\, (n-1) \big) \,+\, 2
$$

- repeat essentially the same process to now fold the constant into the general term

$$
\begin{align}
a_n \,+\, n \,+\, \color{red}{??} &\,=\, 2 \big( a_{n-1}\,+\, (n-1) \big) \,+\, 2  \,+\, \color{red}{??}\\
&\,=\, 2 \big( a_{n-1}\,+\, (n-1) \,+\, \color{red}{??}\big) \,-\, \bcancel{\color{red}{??}} \,+\, \bcancel{2}
\end{align}
$$

- again it follows that $\color{red}{??} = 2$ for the free terms to cancel out, thus in the end

$$a_n + n + 2 = 2 \big(a_{n-1} + (n-1) + 2\big)$$

The latter shows that $a_n + n + 2$ is a geometric progression with common ratio $2\,$, so:

$$
a_n + n + 2 = 2^n (a_0 + 0 + 2 ) \quad\iff\quad a_n = (a_0+2)\,2^n - (n + 2)
$$

The above is technically equivalent to doing it "*by the book*", of course, but the individual steps are small enough that they can be worked out mostly "*by inspection*".

Comment: @B.Mehta This type of an approach works really well when you know what to add, i.e. when you're verifying a formula rather than finding it.

Comment: Ah yes, true. My initial approach would have been as in your response instead!

Comment: @AlexanderBurstein The homogeneous part of the linear recurrence indicates a geometric progression with common ratio $2$. So the idea is to incorporate the "perturbation" term $+n$ into the general term of the sequence such as to reduce it to a GP. Technically you could write $b_n = a_n + \lambda n + \mu\,$, substitute into the given recurrence, and determine that $\lambda = 1, \mu = 2$ gives $b_n = 2 \cdot b_{n-1}\,$. However, this case is arguably simple enough that it can be worked out "by inspection".

Comment: @dxiv It's true, this case is simple and can be done by inspection. I'm simply saying that, in general, working out the "perturbation" requires some effort (e.g. as you indicated for this example).

Comment: @dxiv What you've mentioned in the comment is what exactly I have done up till now but i did not get the hint. Could you please elaborate further?

Comment: @ShreyaBhandari Too long for a comment, I edited the answer and elaborated some more.

Answer (score 5):

So we have $a_0=0$ and $a_n=2a_{n-1}+n$ for $n\ge 1$. Let $A(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{a_n x^n}$. Then multiplying both sides of the recurrence by $x^n$ and summing over $n\ge 1$, we get
$$
\begin{split}
A(x)=A(x)-a_0&=2xA(x)+\sum_{n\ge 1}{n x^n}\\
&=2xA(x)+x\left(\sum_{n\ge 0}{x^n}\right)'\\
&=2xA(x)+x\left(\frac{1}{1-x}\right)'\\
&=2xA(x)+\frac{x}{(1-x)^2},
\end{split}
$$
so $(1-2x)A(x)=\dfrac{x}{(1-x)^2}$ and hence
$$
A(x)=\frac{x}{(1-2x)(1-x)^2}=\dfrac{2}{1-2x}-\dfrac{1}{(1-x)^2}-\frac{1}{1-x},
$$
so that $a_n=[x^n]A(x)=2\cdot2^n-(n+1)-1=2^{n+1}-n-2$.

Comment: Please pardon me but i am still confused. I have 3 questions. First, how did you think of supposing that $A(x)$ .   
 Second , when you are expanding the $A(x)$ , in the 2nd step, does that parentheses indicate derivative, if yes, then why are taking the derivative?    And third, how does the computed A(x) imply $a(n) = [x^n] A(x)$ ? TIA

Comment: @ShreyaBhandari Use of generating functions is a standard technique for solving such recurrences. See, for example, Wilf's [_generatingfunctionology_](http://www.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/gfologyLinked2.pdf). The parentheses don't indicate derivative, but the prime after them does. $a_n$ is the coefficient at $x^n$ of $A(x)$, so we compute the coefficients at $x^n$ in all the partial fractions.